# Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore 3.0.0-beta13 Not working on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform

**Purpose**

Use Google Cloud Diagnostics on a .net core 2.2 REST API, for Logging, Tracing and Error Reporting in two possible scenarios:

1. Local execution on Visual Studio 2017
2. Deployed on a Docker Container and Running on a GCP Kubernetes Engine

**Environment details**

- .NET version: 2.2.0
- Package name and version: Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore 3.0.0-beta13

**Description**

For configuring Google Cloud Diagnostics, two documentation sources were used:

1. [Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore/)
2. [Enable configuration support for Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore   #2435](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/2435)

Based on the above documentation the UseGoogleDiagnostics extension method on IWebHostBuilder was used, as this configures Logging, Tracing and Error Reporting middleware.

According to the 2) link, the following table presents the information needed when using the UseGoogleDiagnostics method:
[image: Configuration Table]

1. For local execution => project_id, module_id, and version_id are needed,
2. For GKE => module_id, and version_id

The .net core configuration files were used to provide the above information for each deployment:

*appsettings.json*

```
{
  "GCP": {
    "ServiceID": "my-service",
    "VersionID": "v1"
  } 
}
```

*appsettings.Development.json*

```
{
  "GCP": {
    "ID": "my-id"
  } 
}
```

Basically, the above will render the following configuration:

1. On Local execution

```cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseGoogleDiagnostics("my-id", "my-service", "v1")
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

2. On GKE

```cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseGoogleDiagnostics(null, "my-service", "v1")
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

To guarantee i'm using the correct information, i used two places on the GCP UI to verify:

1. On Endpoints Listing, checked the service details:

```
Service name: my-service Active version: v1
```

2. Checked the Endpoint logs, for a specific API POST Endpoint

```
{
insertId: "e6a63a28-1451-4132-ad44-a4447c33a4ac@a1"  

jsonPayload: {…}  
 logName: "projects/xxx%2Fendpoints_log"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-07-11T21:03:34.851569606Z"  

resource: {

labels: {
   location: "us-central1-a"    
   method: "v1.xxx.ApiOCRPost"    
   project_id: "my-id"    
   service: "my-service"    
   version: "v1"    
  }
  type: "api"   
 }
 severity: "INFO"  
 timestamp: "2019-07-11T21:03:27.397632588Z"  
}
```

**Am i doing anything wrong or is it a bug on Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore 3.0.0-beta13?**

When executing the service Endpoints, for each specific deployment, Google Cloud Diagnostics behaves differently:

1. On Local execution (VS2017) => Logging, Tracing and Error Reporting work as expected, everything showing in GCP UI
2. On GKE Deployment => Logging, Tracing and Error Reporting DO NOT Work, nothing shows in GCP UI

I've tried several variations, hardcoding the values directly in the code, etc, but no matter what i do, Google Cloud Diagnostics is not working when deployed in GKE:

1. Hardcoding the values directly

```cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseGoogleDiagnostics(null, "my-service", "v1")
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

2. Without the v in Version

```cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseGoogleDiagnostics(null, "my-service", "1")
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```